# Is it only natural that my chained POST and GET axios calls are getting slower?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I believe ( not completely sure ), that my code became a bit slower after chaining the POST and GET calls and was wondering if that's normal or if there's another more efficient way of doing this. I base my assumption on the fact that I see the google map marker appearing after a slight delay on the google map. I believe this is because I am pushing the newly created marker in the markers: [] array at the end of the chained POST and GET.

Originally my code looked like this:

```
createMarker(event){
    axios.post('/marker', {
        userId: this.$store.state.auth.userId,
        marker: event.latLng
    }).then(response => {
        this.markers.push({ 'id': response.data.marker.id,
                            'lat': response.data.marker.lat,
                            'lng': response.data.marker.lng})
    }).catch((error) => console.log(error));
}
```

The updated version chains a POST request in the GET `.then()` like this:

```
        createMarker(event){
            var lat = event.latLng.lat();
            var lng = event.latLng.lng();
            const latLng = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + lat + ',' + lng + '&key='

            axios.get(latLng)
            .then(response => {
                const name = response.data.results[0].address_components[5].long_name + ', '
                            + response.data.results[0].address_components[3].long_name
                console.log(response)
                axios.post('/marker', {
                    userId: this.$store.state.auth.userId,
                    marker: event.latLng,
                    name: name
                }).then(response => {
                    this.markers.push({ 'id': response.data.marker.id,
                                        'lat': response.data.marker.lat,
                                        'lng': response.data.marker.lng})
                }).catch((error) => console.log(error));
            }).catch((error) => console.log(error))
        }
```

I have to chain the methods because I want to use google's geocode api to get the city name based on lat and lng and then pass it to my POST request so I can save it to my own database.

Comment: Do not trust the value of `userId: this.$store.state.auth.userId,` in your `axios.post`. If user is logged in, you should be able to get that user id on the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `id` is not required for the marker to show on the map, try this:

Add the marker with empty `id` before GET/POST calls. This way there shouldn't be any delays.

And update the `id` value once your POST calls finishes.

Check the comments in the code

```
createMarker(event){
    var lat = event.latLng.lat();
    var lng = event.latLng.lng();
    const latLng = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + lat + ',' + lng + '&key='

    // add the marker to the map first
    this.markers.push({ 'id':  '',
                        'lat': lat,
                        'lng': lng})
    // save the position of the marker, so we can add `id` later
    var index = this.markers.length - 1;

    axios.get(latLng)
        .then(response => {
            const name = response.data.results[0].address_components[5].long_name + ', '
                       + response.data.results[0].address_components[3].long_name

            console.log(response)
            axios.post('/marker', {
                userId: this.$store.state.auth.userId,
                marker: event.latLng,
                name: name
            }).then(response => {
                // update marker index
                this.markers[index].id = response
            }).catch((error) => console.log(error));
        }).catch((error) => console.log(error))
```

Comment: So I'd need to return the id of the saved marker in my POST response so that I can assign it back?

Comment: Yes. In your **POST** you already have `id: response.data.marker.id,`. But instead of waiting for 2 server calls to finish AND THEN show the marker, you show the marker, do 2 server calls, and then update marker id.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right. The final result is the delay of two network requests. However, you are not correctly utilizing the promise chain. It resembles the callback hell. You can write it in a more elegant fashion like:

```
createMarker(event) {
    var lat = event.latLng.lat();
    var lng = event.latLng.lng();

    const latLng = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + lat + ',' + lng + '&key=';

    const userId = this.$store.state.auth.userId;

    axios.get(latLng)
        .then((response) => response.data.results[0])
        .then((x) => `${x.address_components[5].long_name},${x.address_components[3].long_name}`)
        .then((name) => axios.post('/marker', {
            name, userId
            marker: event.latLng,
        }))
        .then((response) => this.markers.push({ 
            id: response.data.marker.id,
            lat: response.data.marker.lat,
            lng: response.data.marker.lng
        }))
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
}
```

Promises help you flatten nested asynchronous calls.

Comment: May I ask what is going on here. I don't think I've seen those $ in JavaScript so far. Where can I read about them so I can figure it out? - .then((x) => `${x.address_components[5].long_name},${x.address_components[3].long_name}`)

Comment: These are called as [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). They are the new features of ES2015. It is basically a string interpolation.

Comment: @Bobimaru Note the use of backtick ` character instead of regular quotes.